# How to do routing in Play framework?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, playframework, playframework-2.0

I am new to `Play Framework` and trying to setup a very small project in `Intellij`. So, I followed some basic steps:

1. Create a new project in Intellij
2. Run it with play framework and it works (localhost:9000)
3. Now I have added a new `Java` class file in Controller package.
4. Add routes configuration in `config/routes` file.

## TestController.java

```
public class TestController extends Controller {

public F.Promise<Result> createTest() {
    return F.Promise.promise(() -> TestEndpoints.createTest(Json.fromJson(request().body().asJson(),
            Test.class))).map((result) -> ok(Json.toJson(result)));
}
```

## Routes

```
POST    /Test    controllers.TestController.createTest()
```

When I run the project I got this error:

```
value createTest is not a member of object controllers.TestController
```

Why is this happening. One thing I just noticed that my Controller folder has `Application.scala` not `Application.java`. What I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Which play version are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Play switched to using dependency injection and therefore the way to reference a function in your Controller is:

POST    /Test    @controllers.TestController.createTest()

Notice the '@'

Comment: Ok. It works but then why this routing is working `# Home page
GET     /                           controllers.Application.index()`

Comment: So if you declare the Controller as a class then it needs to be injected to create a new instance. If however you declare the Controller as an object then it already has an instance and it doesnt need to be injected. This being said, Play has made a move towards dependency injection so you should try to use that and avoid Global state.